# Managing build versions in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, dll, versioning

I often build libraries and websites and my versions are naturally always at 1.0.0.0.

How do you guys manage the versions to increment automatically?

Also, how can you specify a seed for example: I want to start at 0.5.0.0 and increment to 0.5.0.1, 0.5.0.2, 0.5.0.3, etc...

Or starting at 1.0.0.0 and increment like 1.0.1.0, 1.0.2.0, 1.0.3.0.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just adjust the variable in your project/Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs.

From left to right you can either enter manually your Major, Minor, Revision and Build-Numbers, or you can substitute them with a '*' and let VisualStudio increment them with each build.

Comment: Thanks, that involves both manual and automatic intervention and I like the fact that its built-in.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for the question! I thought about it before, you've just reminded me.

Now I've found visual studio add-in for that purposes:

[Build Version Increment Add-In Visual Studio](http://autobuildversion.codeplex.com/)

I've installed and tested it - works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Versioning Controlled Build](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/versioningcontrolledbuild.aspx)